# How to have both UILabel and UIButton items into a UIView for UITableView header section

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

This is my first post here, so I hope to do everything correctly.
I'm trying to write a code in Objective-C that allows me to add a UIButton in a table header view, for a specific section.

This is how it should look:

[image: 1]

I see correctly the title, but unfortunately the UIButton doesn't appear and I don't know why.. some months ago I've used a similar code and it worked, but after changing something due to another bug in the table view, it stopped working and unfortunately I haven't the original code anymore..
Do you know where I'm wrong or do you know any alternative?

This is the code in Objective-C (that should automatically align the title and the button, even when the user changes the device orientation and it should work for any screen size):

```
-(UIView*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (section == 2) {
        UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 0,0)];
        [view setClipsToBounds:NO];
        [view setPreservesSuperviewLayoutMargins:TRUE];
        UILabel *textLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        textLabel.text = @"MY TITLE";
        textLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.427f green:0.427f blue:0.427f alpha:1.0f];
        //[textLabel setFont:_tableViewFooterFont];
        [textLabel setTextAlignment:4]; // Natural
        [textLabel setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:FALSE];
        [textLabel setAccessibilityTraits:UIAccessibilityTraitHeader];
        [view addSubview:textLabel];
        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:1];
        //[button setHidden:FALSE];
        //[button.titleLabel setFont:_tableViewFooterFont];
        [button.titleLabel setTextColor:[UIColor redColor]];
        [button setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:FALSE];
        [button setTitle:@"RESET" forState:0];
        [button setContentCompressionResistancePriority:0 forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisHorizontal];
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(resetAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [view addSubview:button];
        NSDictionary *dictionary = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(textLabel, button);
        NSLayoutConstraint *buttonConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|-[textLabel]->=0-[button]-|" options:0 metrics:NULL views:dictionary];
        [view addConstraints:buttonConstraint];
        NSLayoutConstraint *labelConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-12-[textLabel]-6-|" options:0 metrics:NULL views:dictionary];
        [view addConstraints:labelConstraint];
        NSLayoutConstraint *viewConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:button attribute:10 relatedBy:0 toItem:textLabel attribute:10 multiplier:1.0 constant:0];
        [view addConstraint:viewConstraint];
        return view;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
-(UIView*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // create view for header
    UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 40)]; // set header view height as you want
    headerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor] ;

    // create label for header title
    UILabel *title = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, tableView.frame.size.width-130, 30)];
    title.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"FONT_NAME" size:16.0];  //optional
    [title.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:30].active = true;
    [title.widthAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:tableView.frame.size.width-130].active = true;

    // create button for header action
    UIButton *resetButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.yourTableView.frame.size.width-120, 0, 120, 30)];
    [resetButton setTitle:@"RESET" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    //resetButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [resetButton setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [resetButton setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"FONT_NAME" size:16.0]] ;
    [resetButton.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:30].active = true;
    [resetButton.widthAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:120].active = true;

    //Stack View
    UIStackView *stackView = [[UIStackView alloc] initWithFrame:headerView.frame];

    stackView.axis = UILayoutConstraintAxisHorizontal;
    stackView.distribution = UIStackViewDistributionFillProportionally;
    stackView.alignment = UIStackViewAlignmentCenter;
    stackView.spacing = 10;


    [stackView addArrangedSubview:title];
    [stackView addArrangedSubview:resetButton];

    stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
    [headerView addSubview:stackView];

    if(section == 2){
        title.text = @"MY TITLE";
        [resetButton addTarget:self action:@selector(resetBtnActn:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside] ;

    }else{

        headerView.hidden = YES ;
        title.hidden = YES ;
        resetButton.hidden = YES ;
    }

    //Trailing
    NSLayoutConstraint *trailing =[NSLayoutConstraint
                                    constraintWithItem:stackView
                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                    relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                    toItem:headerView
                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                    multiplier:1.0f
                                    constant:0.f];

    //Leading

    NSLayoutConstraint *leading = [NSLayoutConstraint
                                       constraintWithItem:stackView
                                       attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                       relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                       toItem:headerView
                                       attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeadingMargin
                                       multiplier:1.0f
                                       constant:0.f];

    //Bottom
    NSLayoutConstraint *bottom =[NSLayoutConstraint
                                     constraintWithItem:stackView
                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                     relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                     toItem:headerView
                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                     multiplier:1.0f
                                     constant:0.f];

    //Add constraints
    [headerView addConstraint:trailing];
    [headerView addConstraint:bottom];
    [headerView addConstraint:leading];

    // 5. Finally return
    return headerView;            

}

// table section button action
-(IBAction)resetBtnActn:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"button tapped");

}
```

- comment if you have any issue.

Comment: Posting just a code is not a good way to answer , You should put some description where you can show what is the problem and how your code helps to fix this :) , with that Your answer also be helpful to others who is looking for the same solution

Comment: Thanks for your help! Your code shows the UIButton, but unfortunately after changing the device orientation it's not aligned anymore. This was one of the reasons why I've added those constraints.

Comment: @Ram2048 can you share the ss what exactly wrong after device orientation was changed

Comment: @Nick it works for both portrait and landscape modes when I open that controller, but if I rotate the display (in this case from portrait to landscape) this is the result: https://imgur.com/a/WP86JOG  I would want to avoid to reload that header every time the device changes orientation, seen that it's a bad practice..

Comment: @Nick thanks, but unfortunately it's the same. I think it is because the view is created with tableView.frame.size.width, and the width changes when I rotate the device, but the view is with the old width.

Comment: @Nick yes, I've obviously done it (otherwise I couldn't compile the code, I've also replaced "moreButton" with "resetButton"), but the UIButton persists to be misaligned when I change orientation (note that my table view has an autoresizingMask, I don't know if it depends from that..)

Comment: @Ram2048 I'll check and let you know

Comment: Reload the table view  after rotation with some time delay. You can write the code in  ViewWillTransitionToSize method. No Need auto layouts.

Comment: You wrote constraints only for button. Section header also created programatically. Where is constraints for view. Check by giving background colour to your view. Button is in correct place. Your UIView is not resizing.

Comment: I've discovered that my code works perfectly (both portrait and landscape and it works rotating the display removing the line [button setContentCompressionResistancePriority:0 forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisHorizontal];  thanks anyway for your help and suggestions!

Comment: @Ram2048 check and replay code with edited answer, it's working for landscape and portrait mode.